# NSTimer Xcode Warning

Tags: iphone, xcode, nstimer, compiler-warnings

I have an `NSTimer` that I initialize with `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:` with a very short interval (.1 seconds) with no repeat, and then never use it again as it invalidates itself and therefore releases its retain on the target. Xcode warns that it is an unused variable, and I was curious if there was a sensible way to get rid of the warning (The yellow upsets my eyeballs!)

Thanks.

Comment: Remove the variable and leave the expression on the right side of the assignment?

Comment: Wow how did I not realize that? thanks for answers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

if you don't use it again don't save it in a variable.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.4 target:self selector:@selector(timer:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

will work perfectly fine

Answer (score 2):

Just don't assign the result to anything if you aren't going to use the return value.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:...];
```